# Content Query Web App - Additional Filters Question

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

I am trying to setup a content query to look at documents checked out to [ME] so that users can see what files are checked out to them.  However, the Checked Out To filter is not in the Additional Filters list.  It appears to be a standard item.  Why is it missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed the same issue myself.  I used a standard OOTB CQWP.

**Insert CQWP to page:**

[image]

I wanted to summarise all checked out `Documents` in the Site Collection.  Therefore I did not apply any filters besides indicating `List Type = Document Library`.

[image]

Scroll down to **Presentation/Fields to Display**

[image]

Results of the content query; it shows a name next to a file.  Not all names show up yet - I believe there is some kind of a crawl(?) that needs to happen to refresh the CQWP results.  Although, on further reading, there seems to be a [cache issue (this link is for 2010!)](http://www.sharepointbloggers.com/2011/01/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part.html) sometimes with CQWP queries.  In case you have the same issue, I thought I'd post [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602408/cqwp-renders-only-in-edit-mode/4602449#4602449) which contains a possible way to resolve the issue.

[image]